# Troubleshooting a P5.js animation bug

Tags: javascript, animation, p5.js

I'm trying to build a continuous animation that connects the dots based on a simple algorithm.
The end result will look like this, https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/c7BygWs3c
The animation will look like this, https://editor.p5js.org/knectar/sketches/lpn3kSO7D.

The code is below.

It seems like it's close, but after the first element animates as expected, the remainder of the path just fills out in one frame.

Any suggestions?

```
var zag;

var spacing = 125;
var ready = false;

var nodeCounter; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  zag = new Zag();

  nodeCounter = zag.comboArr.length - 1;

}

function draw() {

  background(0);

  translate(200, 0);


  zag.animateLine(nodeCounter);


  if (ready) {

    ready = false;
    nodeCounter--;
    console.log(nodeCounter);

  }

  // zag.display();
}

class Zag {

  constructor() {
    this.nodeCount = 4;
    this.comboArr = [];
    this.setArrs();
    this.combineArr();
  }

  animateLine(index) {

    let tempX, tempY;

    let first = this.comboArr[index];
    let next = this.comboArr[index - 1];

    tempX = map(frameCount, 0, 100, first.x, next.x, 1);
    tempY = map(frameCount, 0, 100, first.y, next.y, 1);

    stroke(25, 22, 220);
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(10);

    line(first.x, first.y, tempX, tempY);

    if (tempX == next.x && tempY == next.y) {
      ready = true;
      console.log(nodeCounter);

    }

  }




  setArrs() {
    this.baseArrA = [];
    this.baseArrB = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= this.nodeCount; i++) {
      this.baseArrA.push(i);
      this.baseArrB.push(i);
    }
    this.shuffleArr(this.baseArrA);
    this.shuffleArr(this.baseArrB);

  }

  combineArr() {

    for (let i = 0; i <= this.nodeCount - 1; i++) {
      this.comboArr.push(createVector(0, this.baseArrA[i] * spacing));
      this.comboArr.push(createVector(spacing, this.baseArrB[i] * spacing));
    }

  }

  shuffleArr(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
  }

  display() {

    let i = 1;
    fill(200);
    noStroke();
    textSize(15);
    for (let item of this.comboArr) {
      text(i + ": " + item.x + ":" + item.y, item.x + 10, item.y - 5);
      i++;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this is that when you do:

```
tempX = map(frameCount, 0, 100, first.x, next.x, 1);
tempY = map(frameCount, 0, 100, first.y, next.y, 1);
```

you're expecting that `frameCount` is between `0` and `100`. In fact, `frameCount` keeps increasing, and the drawing speed keeps increasing, too.

Try changing the two lines to:

```
var tempFrameCount = frameCount % 100;
    
tempX = map(tempFrameCount, 0, 99, first.x, next.x, 1);
tempY = map(tempFrameCount, 0, 99, first.y, next.y, 1);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code.

- `frameCount` does not work well for the `map` function because we need to reset it to zero for each line. We can work around this by keeping a dedicated count variable that gets reset to zero every time it reaches 100
- Checking that the `x` and `y` positions have reached the next point does not work well because they may never match exactly. If we use our new `count` variable we don't have to check line end point positions

Here is code similar to your sketch that uses the independent `count` variable

```js
var zag;

var spacing = 125;
var ready = false;

var nodeCounter; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  zag = new Zag();
  nodeCounter = zag.comboArr.length - 1;
  background(0);
  frameRate(20);
}

function draw() {
  translate(200, 0);
  zag.animateLine(nodeCounter);
  if (ready && nodeCounter > 1) {
    ready = false;
    nodeCounter--;
  }
}
var count = 0;
class Zag {
  constructor() {
    this.nodeCount = 4;
    this.comboArr = [];
    this.setArrs();
    this.combineArr();
  }

  animateLine(index) {
    let tempX, tempY;

    let first = this.comboArr[index];
    let next = this.comboArr[index - 1];
    count++;
    tempX = map(count, 0, 100, first.x, next.x, 1);
    tempY = map(count, 0, 100, first.y, next.y, 1);

    stroke(25, 22, 220);
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(10);

    line(first.x, first.y, tempX, tempY);
    if (count > 99){
      ready = true;
      count = 0;
    }
  }

  setArrs() {
    this.baseArrA = [];
    this.baseArrB = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= this.nodeCount; i++) {
      this.baseArrA.push(i);
      this.baseArrB.push(i);
    }
    this.shuffleArr(this.baseArrA);
    this.shuffleArr(this.baseArrB);
  }

  combineArr() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.nodeCount - 1; i++) {
      this.comboArr.push(createVector(0, this.baseArrA[i] * spacing));
      this.comboArr.push(createVector(spacing, this.baseArrB[i] * spacing));
    }

  }

  shuffleArr(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```